# MSM Move entry from site A to Site B

Tags: multi-site-manager

Within two sites under Multiple Site Manager, what would be the easiest way for an editor (ie:from the CP) to move or duplicate an entry from siteA to siteB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly: copying and pasting.

Since sites don't share fields, you'd have to setup a custom module which mapped fields between sites, then have it run a script to migrate the content for you. Then add third party fieldtypes into the mix and things could get even more complicated.